# Авторизация на сервере через POST HTTP-запрос с Android

Tags: android, http, post, redirect, wildfly

Пишется приложение на Android для сервера WildFly. 
Со стороны сервера вход под своим логином и паролем на сайт со страницы авторизации выглядит так:

```
@WebServlet(name = "LoginServlet", urlPatterns = "/login.do")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    SecurityManager sm = new SecurityManager();

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String email = request.getParameter("email").toLowerCase();
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

        if (sm.checkUser(email, pass)){
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", email);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/testpage");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
        }
    }
}
```

Также есть `WebFilter`, не пускающий на `/testpage`пользователя, если у сессии нет атрибута `user`. Это достигается следующим методом в классе `LogiFilter`:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null;

    if (loggedIn) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
    }
}
```

При попытке осуществления авторизации через браузер сервер адекватно отрабатывает согласно имеющейся в БД паре log | pass. В зависимости от выданного атрибута `user` на дочерней странице `/testpage` отображается соответствующая авторизованному пользователю информация.

Тем не менее, при попытке авторизации с приложения Android несмотря на отправку методом POST верной (не верной в том числе) пары log | pass атрибут `user` не закрепляется, из-за чего происходит редирект со страницы `/testpage` на страницу авторизации. Код осуществления POST-запроса:

```
private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>  {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... data) {
            final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

            try {   
                StringBuilder tokenUri = new StringBuilder("email=");
                tokenUri.append(URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8"));
                tokenUri.append("&pass=");
                tokenUri.append(URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8"));



                String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/sendmsg/login.do";
                URL obj = new URL(url);
                //HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "UTF-8");
                //con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

                con.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                outputStreamWriter.write(tokenUri.toString());
                outputStreamWriter.flush();

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
                System.out.println("Post parameters : " + tokenUri);
                System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
                System.out.println("Response Body : " + con.getResponseMessage());

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                };
                in.close();

            System.out.println(response.toString());

            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //new GetTask().execute();
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

При использовании параметра `HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);` редирект не производится, а response code становится равным 307 (Temporary Redirect). При попытке получить GET-запросом `/testpage` приходит response code 302 (Found). При включении редиректа в любом случае приходит страница авторизации.

Не исключено, что требуется ручное присвоение сессии атрибутов или использование cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вы верно подметили, `HttpURLConnection` сам сессиями и куками не занимается, ему их надо каждый раз выставлять.

Как пример, можете посмотреть образец кода на enSO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171708/5479247

Comment: Если клиент имеет прямой доступ к атрибутам `HttpSession`, то нельзя идентифицировать пользователя по нему: он может установить себе любое значение. Но разве это не стандартная практика? Я не раз видел, как `session.setAttribute("userName", userName);` использовался в сервлетах, если нет возможности использовать готовое решение, вроде Spring Security.

Comment: `HttpSession` [хранится](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240556/when-should-i-use-session-variables-instead-of-cookies) на сервере и пользователь не имеет к ней доступа.

Comment: А как по вашему сервер понимает, что вот этот клиент уже был и вот его сессия? Он пишет id сессии (или еще чего) в куки, вот поэтому куки и надо отправлять при повторном запросе.